# File mapping in C and reading the content from the mapped region

Tags: c

The following program compiles and runs successfully and displays output correctly (for most part). However, there are some unwanted characters displaying as well. I would appreciate if you can highlight the issue.

```
/* 
 This is just a demo file of something larger project..
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>   // for mmap()
#include <sys/stat.h>   // to get the file size
#include <fcntl.h>      // for O_RDWR

typedef struct fruits{
    int serialnumber;
    char fruitName[30];
}fruitInfo;

fruitInfo fruit[4];

// Assign values to the structure fields
void createFruitInfo(int index, int serialnumber, char *fruitName){
    fruit[index].serialnumber = serialnumber;
    strncpy(fruit[index].fruitName, fruitName, strlen(fruitName));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    
    // Step 1: Create a file
    createFruitInfo(0, 1, "Apple");
    createFruitInfo(1, 2, "Banana");
    createFruitInfo(2, 3, "Cherry");
    createFruitInfo(3, 4, "Damson plum");

    // Write to a file
    FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "w");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        fwrite (&fruit[i], sizeof(fruitInfo), 1, fp);
    }
    fclose(fp); // close the file

    // Read from a file
    fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    fruitInfo buffer1;  // fread reads data from the given stream into the memory pointed to by buffer

    while(fread (&buffer1, sizeof(fruitInfo), 1, fp)){
        printf("%d %s\n", buffer1.serialnumber, buffer1.fruitName);
    }

    fclose(fp); // close the file
    
    // Step 2: Map the file from the disk to the memory
    
    // Get the size of the file
    struct stat st; // structure st to store the file information
    stat("file.txt", &st);
    off_t size = st.st_size;

    // Open the file for reading
//  FILE *fp;   // file pointer 
//  fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    int fd = open("file.txt", O_RDONLY);

    // create the memory mapping
//  int fd = fileno(fp);    // convert file pointer to file descriptor
    //fruitInfo *ptr = mmap(NULL, st.st_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    fruitInfo *ptr = mmap(NULL, st.st_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);    

    // close the file
    close(fd);

    // Step 3: Display the content of the mapped memory
    fruitInfo buffer;   // fread reads data from the given stream into the memory pointed to by buffer

    int number;
    char Name[30];

    //int i = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        number = ptr[i].serialnumber;
        strncpy(Name, ptr[i].fruitName, strlen(ptr[i].fruitName));
        printf("%d \t %s\n", number, Name);
        for (int j = 0; j <  strlen(Name); j++){
            printf("\t %d", Name[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        //i++;
    }

    // Step 4: Ummap the memory
    munmap(ptr, st.st_size);
    
    // Step 5: Verify the content from a file
    fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    fruitInfo fileBuffer;   // fread reads data from the given stream into the memory pointed to by buffer

    printf("\n\nVerifying from the file:\n");
    while(fread (&fileBuffer, sizeof(fruitInfo), 1, fp)){
        printf("%d %s\n", fileBuffer.serialnumber, fileBuffer.fruitName);
        for (int j = 0; j <  strlen(fileBuffer.fruitName); j++){
            printf("\t %d", fileBuffer.fruitName[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(fp); // close the file
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
1    Apple
     65  112     112     108     101     127     0
2    Banana
     66  97  110     97  110     97  0
3    Cherry
     67  104     101     114     114     121     0
4    Damson plum�V
     68  97  109     115     111     110     32  112     108     117     109     -37     25  86  0
```

Verifying from the file:

```
1 Apple
     65  112     112     108     101     0
2 Banana
     66  97  110     97  110     97  0
3 Cherry
     67  104     101     114     114     121     0
4 Damson plum
     68  97  109     115     111     110     32  112     108     117     109     0
```

Following at the places of issue:

- At the output "Apple", you can see the character DEL (ASCII code 127). Not sure where it come from.
- At output Damson plum, lot of unnecessary characters: (ASCII code -37),  CTRL-Y (ASCII code 25), V (ASCII code 86). Not sure where they come from.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Aside: ```// Open the file for reading
    FILE *fp;   // file descriptor  
    fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");// close the file
    close(fd);``` ===>1)  Please don't comment such things. `close(fd)` and `fopen (fp, "r")` is clear enough. And that's a `FILE *`, not a file descriptor. 2) `fopen()` + `fileno()` can be replaced with a call to `open()`. 3) Check the return values of library functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This copies up to `strlen(...)` characters, i.e. **excluding** the terminating NUL character and then `printf("...%s...", ...)` that unterminated string (which is undefined behaviour, but actually just continues until the next NUL character to be found in memory):

```
        strncpy(Name, ptr[i].fruitName, strlen(ptr[i].fruitName));
        printf("%d \t %s\n", number, Name);
```

The loop limit for printing the characters as integers is `strlen(Name)`, i.e. the string length of the unterminated string which is also undefined behaviour which actually happens to go to the same NUL byte until which the above `printf` has printed:

```
        for (int j = 0; j <=  strlen(Name); j++){
            printf("\t %d", Name[j]);
        }
```

When dealing with NUL terminated strings, you must verify that they are actually NUL terminated where you expect them to be.

Comment: Thank you. Just adding the line, Name[len] = 0;, as you suggested fixed my problem. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

A few issues ...

1. Don't use `fopen` for the `mmap` file. Use `open`
2. Don't do `close(fd)` while the file is mapped.
3. `i <= strlen(...)` should be `i < strlen(...)`
4. Don't do: `for (i = 0;  i < strlen(...); ++i)` This is very slow. Instead, do: `size_t len = strlen(...); for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)`
5. After `strncpy`, do: `Name[strlen(ptr[i].fruitName)] = 0;` to add the string terminator.
6. After the open, use `fstat`

---

Here is the cleaned up code. Since I didn't have the input file, I added a function to create one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>                   // for mmap()
#include <sys/stat.h>                   // to get the file size
#include <fcntl.h>                      // for O_RDWR

typedef struct fruits {
    int serialnumber;
    char fruitName[30];
} fruitInfo;

#define DEF(_serno,_name) \
    { .serialnumber = _serno, .fruitName = _name }
const fruitInfo initlist[] = {
    DEF(1,"Apple"),
    DEF(2,"Orange"),
    DEF(3,"Banana"),
    DEF(4,"Pear"),
    DEF(5,"Tomato"),
    DEF(6,"Peach"),
    DEF(7,"Nectarine"),
    DEF(8,"Persimmon"),
    DEF(9,"Grapefruit"),
    DEF(10,"Blueberry"),
    DEF(11,"Blackberry"),
    DEF(-1,"")
};

void
mkfile(const char *file)
{

    FILE *fp = fopen(file,"w");

    for (const fruitInfo *info = initlist;  info->serialnumber >= 0;  ++info)
        fwrite(info,sizeof(*info),1,fp);

    fclose(fp);
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    const char *file = "orig.txt";
    mkfile(file);

    // Step 1: Map the file from the disk to the memory

    // Open the file for reading
    int fd = open(file,O_RDONLY);

    // Get the size of the file
    // structure st to store the file information
    struct stat st;
    fstat(fd,&st);
    off_t size = st.st_size;

    // create the memory mapping
    // fruitInfo *ptr = mmap(NULL, st.st_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
    // MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    fruitInfo *ptr = mmap(NULL, st.st_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
        MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);

    // Step 2: Display the content of the mapped memory
    //fruitInfo buffer;

    int number;
    char Name[30];

    // int i = 0;
    fruitInfo *cur = ptr;
    for (size_t off = 0;  off < size;  off += sizeof(fruitInfo), ++cur) {
        number = cur->serialnumber;

        size_t len = strlen(cur->fruitName);
        strncpy(Name, cur->fruitName, len);
        Name[len] = 0;

        printf("%d %s\n", number, Name);
        for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
            printf(" %2.2X", Name[j] & 0xFF);
        printf("\n");
    }

    // Step 3: Ummap the memory
    munmap(ptr, size);

    close(fd);

    // Step 4: Verify the content from a file
    FILE *fp = fopen(file, "r");
    fruitInfo fileBuffer;

    // fread reads data from the given stream into the memory pointed to by
    // buffer

    printf("\n\nVerifying from the file:\n");
    while (fread(&fileBuffer, sizeof(fruitInfo), 1, fp)) {
        printf("%d %s\n", fileBuffer.serialnumber, fileBuffer.fruitName);
        size_t len = strlen(fileBuffer.fruitName);
        for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
            printf(" %2.2X", fileBuffer.fruitName[j] & 0xFF);
        printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(fp);                         // close the file

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the program output (actual fruit data will differ):

```
1 Apple
 41 70 70 6C 65
2 Orange
 4F 72 61 6E 67 65
3 Banana
 42 61 6E 61 6E 61
4 Pear
 50 65 61 72
5 Tomato
 54 6F 6D 61 74 6F
6 Peach
 50 65 61 63 68
7 Nectarine
 4E 65 63 74 61 72 69 6E 65
8 Persimmon
 50 65 72 73 69 6D 6D 6F 6E
9 Grapefruit
 47 72 61 70 65 66 72 75 69 74
10 Blueberry
 42 6C 75 65 62 65 72 72 79
11 Blackberry
 42 6C 61 63 6B 62 65 72 72 79

Verifying from the file:
1 Apple
 41 70 70 6C 65
2 Orange
 4F 72 61 6E 67 65
3 Banana
 42 61 6E 61 6E 61
4 Pear
 50 65 61 72
5 Tomato
 54 6F 6D 61 74 6F
6 Peach
 50 65 61 63 68
7 Nectarine
 4E 65 63 74 61 72 69 6E 65
8 Persimmon
 50 65 72 73 69 6D 6D 6F 6E
9 Grapefruit
 47 72 61 70 65 66 72 75 69 74
10 Blueberry
 42 6C 75 65 62 65 72 72 79
11 Blackberry
 42 6C 61 63 6B 62 65 72 72 79
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I implemented your suggestion but it did not helped me. I edited my original code to include the code that is used to write data into the file. May be that will help to rectify the issue. Thanks

Comment: *Don't do `close(fd)` while the file is mapped.* Why?

Comment: Quoting the Linux `mmap(2)` man page: "After the `mmap()` call has returned, the file descriptor `fd` can be closed immediately without invalidating the mapping."

Comment: The comment "Don't do close(fd) while the file is mapped." is not applicable here. The mapping is PRIVATE, so not copying is needed to the file. Yes, if the mapping was SHARED, then fd should not be closed while the file is being mapped.